# rails call action on collection_select change

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, actioncontroller

basically I want to immediately go to an action/path (new_budget_path) after selecting an option from a dropdown menu. I cant figure how solve it and how to order the statements.

```
= collection_select(:budget, :id, Member.list_available_budgets,:title, :title,
options= {prompt: t('view.member.select_budget_box')},
html_options= {onchange: remote_function(url: new_budget_path)})
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
undefined method `remote_function' for #<#<Class:0x007ff5fc6fa0c8>:0x007ff602bba698>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Where is `remote_function` defined?

Comment: is it not a helper method from actionhelper?

Comment: Oh right, it is, never used it before.

Comment: `remote_function` doesn't exist in Rails anymore. Last Rails version which had it is 3.0.9 (Reference: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/remote_function)